# Can I use logspout for global syslog logging on Docker swarm?

Tags: logging, docker, docker-swarm, papertrail-app

I have a single docker host running Docker 1.12 working well and am able to use [gliderlabs/logspout](https://hub.docker.com/r/gliderlabs/logspout/) to centralize docker logs to papertrail.

Is it possible to deploy this configuration to all nodes on a [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/)?

I have tried:

```
    docker service create --name logspout --mode=global \
        gliderlabs/logspout \
        syslog+tls://<yourhost>.papertrailapp.com:<yourport>
```

but the service dies and respawns continuously. On the docker (non-swarm instance) you need to map the docker socket `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` a la the [papertrail docs](http://help.papertrailapp.com/kb/configuration/configuring-centralized-logging-from-docker/). Is this possible in a swarm service? How do you mount the docker socket into the service?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** the current `gliderlabs/logspout` container appears to **stop** logging after the first connect. After much googling for results (seems to point to a bunch of timeout/reconnect issues). I decided to move to docker's `--log-driver` option instead. This meant touching every machine and restarting the daemon, but there was no interruption of service, apart from the pain of editing the `/etc/default/docker` file on my ubuntu instances and restarting docker.

**Original answer**

Thanks to a brilliant piece of research in [this article by Sematext](https://sematext.com/blog/2016/09/19/docker-swarm-mode-full-cluster-monitoring-logging-with-1-command/) I discovered the magical bind command:

```
docker service create --name logspout \
    --mode=global -e SYSLOG_TAG=swarm --publish <yourport>:<yourport> \
    --mount type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock \
    gliderlabs/logspout syslog+tls://<yourhost>.papertrailapp.com:<yourport>
```

The magic is in the `--mount type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock` command. It is also advantageous to use `SYSLOG_TAG` to identify the syslogs as coming from your swarm because by default the hostname is the container ID (which can change and are rather opaque). It appears that you also need to publish/expose the logging port of the logging fails at random.

If I add a node to the swarm, this service is automatically deployed and configured to the new host! Swarm magic!

```
Sep 29 17:07:01 8d551da912a4 swarm:    File "/opt/conda/envs/clientapi/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 646, in __call__
Sep 29 17:07:01 8d551da912a4 swarm:      raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
Sep 29 17:07:01 8d551da912a4 swarm:  werkzeug.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500: Internal Server Error
Sep 29 17:11:05 cd73e5278032 swarm:  ....................
Sep 29 17:11:05 cd73e5278032 swarm:  complete: opportunities = added 0 updated 0 out of 2023
```

You can see container ID and the swarm identifier in an easy to read format